# Python argparse opening multiple files

Tags: python-3.x, argparse

i'm trying to access multiple .txt files with argparse and i've stumbled across a problem which i can't put my head around.

```
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument('filename', nargs='+'. type=argparse.FileType('r'))
    args = parser.parse_args()
    with open(args.filename, 'r') as files:
         #do stuff to files
```

and i'm trying to access with

EDIT:

```
python3 script.py file1.txt file2.txt
```

But i'm getting an error as such:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "script.py", line 34 in <module>
    with open(args.filename, 'r') as files:
TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike objects, not list
```

I somewhat know what that means, but i just can't put my finger on what to do next.

Comment: What is the type of args.filename? I suspect you have a list of strings and not just a string.

Comment: If i understood your question correctly i think it's a string. The script works with one file, but if use it for more than one it says that error.

Comment: `FileType` opens the file for you.  `args.filename` will be a list of open files.  Just read them.  One by one - none of the python file code works with a list of files or filenames.  When debugging `argparse` I recommend `print(args)` so you have a clear(er) idea of what the parser has produced).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From documentation [nargs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#nargs):

> '+'. Just like '*', all command-line args present are gathered **into a list.** Additionally, an error message will be generated if there wasn’t at least one command-line argument present.

So, If you want to open multiple files, u have to iter through your list with args. For example:

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()    
parser.add_argument('filename', nargs='+')
args = parser.parse_args()
for file_name in args.filename:
    with open(file_name, 'r') as files:
        <do your code here>
        # a = files.read()
        # print(a)
```

Comment: Now i'm getting TypeError: expecter str, bytes or os.PathLike, not io.TextIOWrapper,

Comment: @WilleySlippery delete from code `type=argparse.FileType('r')` - not necessery. Updated an answer

Comment: Thank you so much. I've been staring at this for hours.

Comment: @WilleySlippery No problem! If I helped you, mark my answer as correct/useful!Regards!
And remember if you are not using `type` that by default you have args as string, so in this case is useful.